# I am confused please help me solve it

Tags: python

I want to use an dictionary with `b` and `c` like in the code such that when I give input `o`, then I receive 1 as an result with `o`.

```
science_dictionary = {"O": 1, "H": 2}
print("Hey welcome to the chemical reactor")
import time

time.sleep(2)
print("\n")
print("In this chemical reactor you can receive the product of any two "
      "elements")
b = input("Please enter your first element element in short forms : ").upper().strip()
c = input("Please enter your second element element: ").upper().strip()
time.sleep(1)
print("Calculating")
time.sleep(2)
print(f"{b}{c}")
```

Comment: Please choose a suitable title for your question so that other users can help you more easily.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/9401096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access dictionary items by using the dictionary name with the specific key you want. I.e. science_dictionary['O'] will return 1. You can also pass in variable names as keys, for example science_dictionary[b] would be matched with the input (if the input is either O or H).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's your purpose; but i think that if you want to try a make a product using the keys in the dictionary with the inputs [key name] , that would be like this:

```
import time
science_dictionary = {"O": 1, "H": 2}
print("Hey welcome to the chemical reactor")
time.sleep(2)
print("\n")
print("In this chemical reactor you can receive the product of any two elements")
b = input("Please enter your first element element in short forms : ").upper()
c = input("Please enter your second element element: ").upper()
time.sleep(1)
print("Calculating")
time.sleep(2)
print("{}".format(science_dictionary[b] * science_dictionary[c]))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help this is exactly what i wanted